# Opencl code is not running on nvidia gpu

Tags: c++, opencl

I want to run a opencl tutorial file on my system. I have a nvidia gpu and I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I simply compile and run the code on my intel gpu, it compiles but when I am using the nvidia gpu (by simply using the optirun), it cannot find any devices. It is finding the platform, and the platform is going to be created successfully but it cannot find any devices. The nvidia driver which I am using is nvidia-331 and I have installed the nvidia cuda library also which I think it contains the opencl as well.

```
// This program implements a vector addition using OpenCL
// System Include
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// OpenCL include
#include <CL/cl.h>

const char* programsource =
"__kernel                                           \n"
"void vecadd(   __global int* A,                    \n"
"               __global int* B,                    \n"
"               __global int* C)                    \n"
"{                                                  \n"
"   // Get the work item unique id                  \n"
"   int idx = get_global_id(0);                     \n"
"                                                   \n"
"   // Add the corresponding location of            \n"
"   // 'A' and 'B' and store the result in 'C'      \n"
"   C[idx] = A[idx] + B[idx];                       \n"
"}                                                  \n";

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
int* A = NULL;
int* B = NULL;
int* C = NULL;

const int elements = 2048;
size_t datasize = elements * sizeof(int);

A = (int*)malloc(datasize);
B = (int*)malloc(datasize);
C = (int*)malloc(datasize);

for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    A[i] = i;
    B[i] = i;
}

// used to check the output of api call
cl_int status;

// retrieve the number of platforms
cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("%i number of Platforms are detected.\n", numPlatforms);


// allocate enough space for platforms
cl_platform_id* platforms = NULL;
platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id));
status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Platform creation\n");

// retrieve the number of devices
cl_uint numDevices = 0;
status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &numDevices);

printf("%i Devices are detected\n", numDevices);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Device num\n");

// allocate enough space for each device
cl_device_id* devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numDevices, devices, 0);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Device creation\n");

cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, &status);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Context creation\n");

cl_command_queue cmdQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, &status);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Command Queue creation\n");

cl_mem bufA, bufB, bufC;
bufA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  datasize, NULL, &status);
bufB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  datasize, NULL, &status);
bufC = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, datasize, NULL, &status);

status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, bufA, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, A, 0, NULL, NULL);
status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, bufB, CL_FALSE, 0, datasize, B, 0, NULL, NULL);

cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&programsource, NULL, &status);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Program Creation\n");
status = clBuildProgram(program, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful Program Built\n");

cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vecadd", &status);
if(status == CL_SUCCESS)
    printf("Successful kernel creation\n");

status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufA);
status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufB);
status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufC);

// execute the kernel for execution
size_t globalWorkSize[1] = { elements };
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 1, 0, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmdQueue, bufC, CL_TRUE, 0, datasize, C, 0, NULL, NULL);

int result = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    // printf("The value = %i \n", C[i]);
    if(C[i] != i + i)
    {
        result = 0;
        break;
    }
}

if(result == 1)
    printf("output is correct.\n");
else
    printf("output is incorrect.\n");

// Free OpenCL resources
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseCommandQueue(cmdQueue);
clReleaseMemObject(bufA);
clReleaseMemObject(bufB);
clReleaseMemObject(bufC);
clReleaseContext(context);

// Free host resources
free(A);
free(B);
free(C);
free(platforms);
free(devices);

return 0;
}
```

The output on the nvidia gpu is:

```
XXXX@XXXXX-Lenovo-G580:~/Documents/cltuts/add$ optirun ./add
1 number of Platforms are detected.
Successful Platform creation
0 Devices are detected
output is incorrect.
```

but the output on the intel one is:

```
XXX@XXXXXXX-Lenovo-G580:~/Documents/cltuts/add$ ./add
1 number of Platforms are detected.
Successful Platform creation
1 Devices are detected
Successful Device num
Successful Device creation
Successful Context creation
Successful Command Queue creation
Successful Program Creation
Successful Program Built
Successful kernel creation
output is correct.
```

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae what do you mean by the `clinfo`?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae I just can check the status and it say "device not found"

Comment: please run nvidia-smi and provide the output of the tool.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl I dont have the nvidia-smi. I have installed nvidia-331 driver.

Comment: If you have CUDA 6.5 installed you need a driver version of at least 340. I would suggest to install a driver from a CUDA Toolkit not the ubuntu universe drivers.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl But I cannot :(
When I install them, the display screen becomes dark :(

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is likely a driver issue, not a programming one. I'm not sure if you may be able to use open-source drivers whilst using CUDA SDK. I suggest you to migrate this question to AskUbuntu, users there may have extra insight on this matter.